# How to generate the plugin of "Li2018" in Halide on windows and exploit "load_plugin" in other project?

Tags: plugins, halide

reccently, I want to test how does the autoscheduler "Li2018" work on GPU. Firstly, I need to load the plugin of this autoscheduler into my project with function "load_plugin("gradient_autoscheduler")" like the example: https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/apps/gradient_autoscheduler/test.cpp but the biggest problem is, that I cannot generate the plugin on Windows. I have tried to add the "generate_autoscheduler" into the CMakeList.txt in the /apps folder, but it can not work. To compare with autoscheduler "Admas2019" which in the folder /apps/autoscheduler, "Li2018" need a CMakeList.txt to generate the dll plugin, Does some one know how to generate the plugin of "Li2018" on windows? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, we don't have a CMake configuration for Li's autoscheduler, so Windows is not supported yet. I'll put this in my TODO list, but contributions are always welcome. It shouldn't be hard to come up with a CMakeLists.txt based on the Makefile content.